# Java jpa: @OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem using JPA.

I want to the fatherId and father  coexistence,When I query with join table.

```
@Entity
public class Son {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    
    
    @Column(name = "father_id")
    private String fatherId;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "father_id")
    private Father father;
}
```

Comment: So what's the probem? What did you try and didn't work? And why do you need `fatherId` separately as you could also do `father.getId()` without triggering a lazy load (if the entity is using property access - which means you'd need to put the `@Id` annotation on the getter or add `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on the class)?

Comment: Whats the point of having the redundant information in your entity? Father has already all information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set one to read-only.

For example:

```
@Column(name = "father_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String fatherId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "father_id")
private Father father;
```

Otherwise Hibernate has two ways to write the foreign key.